# Как обратиться к методу в ViewController.m из AppDelegate.m?

Tags: objective-c

В `AppDelegate.m` приходят пуш уведомления через сторонний сервис, я хочу по приему пуш уведомления совершать обновление таблицы в ViewController.m, есть у меня там такой метод

```
-(void) updTable
{
    // удаляем все данные старые
[items removeAllObjects];
[items2 removeAllObjects];

    // рефреш таблицы
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Как к нему обратиться из `AppDelegate.m`? 
Ессно, чтобы он знал о чем речь внутри этого метода, т.е. очищал данные и перерисовывал. таблицу.

Comment: интересный метод) как я понимаю, items и items2 нужны для заполнения таблицы, а вы их чистите перед рефрешем.

Comment: Да, чтобы понимать, что кнопка "сработала", это временно.

Comment: В AppDelegate.m сохраняете ссылку на объект (ViewController.m) и когда надо дергаете у этого объекта метод updTable.

Comment: Gimka, Вы советуете зло. Читайте, пожалуйста, мой ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Приветствую!

AppDelegate не должен ничего "знать" о Вашем View Controller, в противном случае вы делаете bad practice.

В данном случае решение напрашивается само собой:

Используйте NSNotification:

где-нибудь в файле, где у вас лежат константы, например **YourServiceConstants.h**, объявляете:

```
static NSString * const ThirdPartyServiceDidSentDataNotification = @"ThirdPartyServiceDidSentDataNotification";
```

в **YourViewController** Вам нужно подписать его на соответствующую нотификацию:

```
#import "YourServiceConstants.h"
...
@implementation YourViewController
- (void)viewDidLoadИлиТамСКакогоМоментаВамНадо {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveNotification:) name:ThirdPartyServiceDidSentDataNotification object:nil];

}
@end

- (void)didReceiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:ThirdPartyServiceDidSentDataNotification]) {
        id notificationData = notification.object; // ваши данные
        // или можно NSDictionary *notificationData = (NSDictionary *)notification.object; если Вы, например, посылаете именно NSDictionary

        // делаете что-то с данными
    }
}
```

А в **AppDelegate** Вы эту нотификацию рассылаете:

```
#import "YourServiceConstants.h"
...
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)тамГдеПриходятПушУведомления {
    id thirdPartyServiceData = ...; // Ваши данные - это может быть NSData, NSString, NSDictionary, NSArray и др.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ThirdPartyServiceDidSentDataNotification object:thirdPartyServiceData]; // если Вы хотите просто послать уведомление (без дополнительных данных, делайте object:nil)
}
@end
```

---

P.S. Если непонятно, почитайте про NSNotification/NSNotificationCenter - они для того и нужны, чтобы разные контроллеры или просто классы могли общаться друг с другом посредством сообщений, то есть нотификаций, не будучи при этом никак между собой связанными напрямую - это не единственный способ связи между классами/контроллерами, но в данном случае я рекомендую Вам использовать именно его.

Кроме того, скорее всего Вам следовало бы вынести функциональность этого стороннего сервиса в какой-нибудь отдельный класс типа YourThirdPartyService, чтобы работа с сервисом и рассылка нотификаций шла оттуда, а не из AppDelegate, ибо AppDelegate - это код, скажем так, **самого общего назначения**, и поэтому нужно избегать добавления в него всего, что имеет свои собственные цель и смысл. В идеале в AppDelegate вообще не должно быть ничего кроме методов протокола `<UIApplicationDelegate>` ([ссылка](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)), которые в этом файле стоят изначально.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать сейчас